# Overlaying a text stream on a video stream with ffmpeg in Node.js

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, javascript, node.js

I am creating a streaming system with Node.js that uses ffmpeg to send video and text streams to a local RTMP server, then combines those streams and sends them to Twitch.

I'm using canvas to create a text image with a transparent background, and I need to change that text every time a new video in the playlist starts.

Currently in stream I see only the video stream of my video and not the text. But if I go via VLC to see each more separate, I see them

However, I'm running into a problem where the text stream doesn't appear in the final video stream on Twitch. In addition, I get the following error message:

```js
Combine stderr: [NULL @ 0x1407069f0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/streamKey'
rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/streamKey: Invalid argument
```

Here is my current Node.js code:

```js
const createTextImage = (runner) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const canvas = createCanvas(1920, 1080);
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Fill the background with transparency
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Set the text options
        context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        context.font = '24px Arial';
        context.textAlign = 'start';
        context.textBaseline = 'middle';

        // Draw the text
        context.fillText(`Speedrun by ${runner}`, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

        // Define the images directory
        const imagesDir = path.join(__dirname, 'images', 'runners');

        // Ensure the images directory exists
        fs.mkdirSync(imagesDir, { recursive: true });

        // Define the file path
        const filePath = path.join(imagesDir, runner + '.png');

        // Create the write stream
        const out = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

        // Create the PNG stream
        const stream = canvas.createPNGStream();

        // Pipe the PNG stream to the write stream
        stream.pipe(out);

        out.on('finish', () => {
            console.log('The PNG file was created.');
            resolve();
        });

        out.on('error', reject);
    });
}
const streamVideo = (video) => {
    ffmpegLibrary.ffprobe(video.video, function (err, metadata) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        currentVideoDuration = metadata.format.duration;

        // Annulez le délai précédent avant d'en créer un nouveau
        if (nextVideoTimeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(nextVideoTimeoutId);
        }

        // Déplacez votre appel setTimeout ici
        nextVideoTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Fin de la vidéo, passage à la suivante...');
            nextVideo();
        }, currentVideoDuration * 1000 + 10000);
    })


    ffmpegVideo = childProcess.spawn('ffmpeg', [
        '-nostdin', '-re', '-f', 'concat', '-safe', '0', '-i', 'playlist.txt',
        '-vcodec', 'libx264',
        '-s', '1920x1080',
        '-r', '30',
        '-b:v', '5000k',
        '-acodec', 'aac',
        '-preset', 'veryfast',
        '-f', 'flv',
        `rtmp://localhost:1935/live/video` // envoie le flux vidéo au serveur rtmp local
    ]);

    createTextImage(video.runner).then(() => {
        ffmpegText = childProcess.spawn('ffmpeg', [
            '-nostdin', '-re',
            '-loop', '1', '-i', `images/runners/${video.runner}.png`, // Utilise l'image créée par Puppeteer
            '-vcodec', 'libx264rgb', // Utilise le codec PNG pour conserver la transparence
            '-s', '1920x1080',
            '-r', '30',
            '-b:v', '5000k',
            '-acodec', 'aac',
            '-preset', 'veryfast',
            '-f', 'flv',
            `rtmp://localhost:1935/live/text` // envoie le flux de texte au serveur rtmp local
        ]);

        ffmpegText.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(`text stdout: ${data}`);
        });

        ffmpegText.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.error(`text stderr: ${data}`);
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(`Erreur lors de la création de l'image de texte: ${error}`);
    });

    ffmpegCombine = childProcess.spawn('ffmpeg', [
        '-i', 'rtmp://localhost:1935/live/video',
        '-i', 'rtmp://localhost:1935/live/text',
        '-filter_complex', '[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0',
        '-s', '1920x1080',
        '-r', '30',
        '-vcodec', 'libx264',
        '-b:v', '5000k',
        '-acodec', 'aac',
        '-preset', 'veryfast',
        '-f', 'flv',
        `rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/${twitchStreamKey}` // envoie le flux combiné à Twitch
    ]);

    ffmpegVideo.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`video stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    ffmpegVideo.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`video stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    ffmpegCombine.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`Combine stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    ffmpegCombine.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`Combine stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    ffmpegCombine.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`ffmpeg exited with code ${code}`);
        if (currentIndex >= playlist.length) {
            console.log('End of playlist');
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Locally I use nginx with rtmp module to manage multi-streams and combined into one to send to twitch

In NGINX it's my nginx.conf for module :

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # le port pour le protocole RTMP
        
        application live {
            live on; # active le streaming en direct
            record off; # désactive l'enregistrement du flux
    
            # définit l'endroit où les flux doivent être envoyés
            push rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/liveKey;
        }
    
        application text {
            live on; # active le streaming en direct
            record off; # désactive l'enregistrement du flux
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked that the codecs, resolution and frame rate are the same for both streams. I am also overlaying the text stream on top of the video stream with the -filter_complex command, but I am not sure if it works correctly.

Does each stream have to have the same parameters?

I would like to know if anyone has any idea what could be causing this problem and how to fix it. Should I use a different format for the output stream to Twitch? Or is there another approach I should consider for layering a dynamic text stream over a video stream?

Also, I'm wondering if I'm handling updating the text stream correctly when the video changes. Currently, I create a new text image with Canvas every time the video changes, then create a new ffmpeg process for the text stream. Is this the right approach, or is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.